# How to enable backspace in incremental search?

Tags: emacs, putty, emacs23

How can change this behaviour:

1. `C-s` — start incremental search
2. type `word` — misprint the last character
3. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> — Oops! incremental search disappears, and I actually delete 1 character from the buffer.

to that one:

1. `C-s` — start incremental search
2. `word` — misprint the last character
3. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> — delete the last `d` character
4. type `k` — `work` — correct, and continue the search

I run Emacs in text terminal via SSH in PuTTY.

Operating system version: 2.6.16.60-0.58.1.1882.3.PTF.638363-smp #1 SMP Wed Dec 2 12:27:56 UTC 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.14.6) of 2010-07-16

With the `-q` option, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> sent by PuTTY is just `C-h`, and it acts like `C-h`, but in my `.emacs`file I it bind to `delete-backward-char`:

```
(global-set-key [(control h)] 'delete-backward-char)
```

Comment: This should work out of the box. What operating system are you using? Are you running Emacs in a GUI or in a text terminal, and which? Do you see the same behavior if you run `emacs -q`? What about `emacs -Q`? What is shown when you press `C-h c Backspace`?

Comment: The answers is above. emacs -Q is like emacs -Q but without welcome screen.

C-h c Backspace - as i said, Backspace is just C-h, being passed through the putty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is configure PuTTY to send `C-?` (byte 127) for <kbd>Backspace</kbd> instead of `C-h` (byte 8). This is the setting that works best in most circumstances. See the 
[PuTTY manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-backspace).

If you changed the PuTTY setting to send `C-h` because some other application didn't work, check that your terminal settings are correct on the server. The setting is often correctly autodetected, but sometimes you may need to add `stty erase '^?'` to your shell configuration file (`.bashrc` or similar) on the server.

If you really absolutely have to have <kbd>Backspace</kbd> send `C-h`, then globally rebinding `C-h` isn't sufficient. Instead, add `(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)` to your `.emacs`. See the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html).

Comment: You are right, I changed Backspace to C-h because to wrong teminal settings in the past, and now it isn't neccessary.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map [(control h)] 'isearch-delete-char)
```

Comment: I changed the answer. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

How you should use Emacs:

1. C-s - start incremental search
2. type **word** - misprint the last character
3. **M-e** - goes into edit-search-word-thing-mode-in-minibuffer :-)
4. correct the typo
5. C-s - continue incremental search